# Database value and display value doesn't match

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a simulator which connects to a MySQL database provided by WAMPServer.

Everything is connected, but the value displayed (using println) and database doesn't match.

The value in database only recorded 0, but the supposed value is 3127. Help me?

```
public void addTotal(String total){
    this.totaltxt.setText(total);
    totalVal = Integer.parseInt(this.totaltxt.getText());
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    if(evt.getSource()==enter){
        main.removeAll();
        main.repaint();
        action.createSim();
        action.startSim();
        db.saveVAL(0,totalVal);
        System.out.println(totalVal);
    }
}
```

Database:

```
public void saveVAL(int sim_time, int sim_total){
    try{
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO sim_energy (sim_time, sim_total)    VALUES ("+sim_time+","+sim_total+")");
        System.out.println("Adding was successful");
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Inserting values unsuccessful");
        //ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: please, print your sql statement...

Comment: You meant this? INSERT INTO sim_energy (sim_time, sim_total)VALUES ("+sim_time+","+sim_total+").

I've already inserted it in my db.java file, as the above.

Comment: The values are successfully inserted in my database, but it is recorded as 0, it should be 3127.

Comment: String sql = "INSERT INTO sim_energy (sim_time, sim_total)    VALUES ("+sim_time+","+sim_total+")"; please print string sql above, it's value will be insert into your db

Comment: It still record as 0. I want it to be recorded as 3127. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: How are `sim_time` and `sim_total` defined on your database?

Comment: Both are integers. It has the same name in the database. Been figuring it out for days, but still no idea to why and how.

Comment: The adding was successful and all the connection is ok, but the recorded value is 0. I tried to change sim_total to String, just for the sake of trial and error. But it is defined as empty string to be entered in the database. But when i call "println", it has a value in it.